# Using Doubles Internally to Generate a Random Integer

Tags: c#, random

I published a bunch of open-source random number generators [on my site](http://www.csharpcity.com/reusable-code/random-number-generators/), including a normally-distributed random number generator. To generate a random integer in the range of 10-20, I would write something like `new NormalRandomGenerator(10, 20).Next()`.

Someone posted this comment:

> Just wondering whether it’s necessary to implement “int Next()” in
>   terms of “double NextDouble()”, as int to double conversions (and
>   visa-versa) can be very slow on some hardware, including recent PC
>   hardware, although I’m not particularly up to date on the latest CPUs
>   at the moment.

I believe this comment refers to the fact that when someone calls `Next(20)` on one of my classes, internally, that call translates to something like `(int)someMersenneTwister.NextDouble() * 20` (I don't remember if I used rounding).

I implemented it this way because MT is both fast and efficient (albeit it has a huge random period). From what I understand, this is the standard way to generate random numbers -- call `Next()` which returns a double in the range [0 .. 1) and then multiply and typecast to an int.

Is there any problem here in terms of my design? Is there a better way (more performant, faster) to generate an integer random number that doesn't use doubles?

Sorry if this sounds vague. I'm not sure if there's even a problem here.

Comment: I don't even understand how integers in a limited range can have a normal/gauss distribution. This distribution returns continuous values all over the real axis.

Comment: Can always mask out bits for smaller numbers, which i guess would be faster. Other then that, I got nothing.

Comment: For *uniform* integers in a given interval check [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9499071/445517) and [my random library](https://github.com/MerkatorProject/Merkator.Tools/tree/master/Merkator.Tools/Random)

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer to your question (because it doesn't make sense in its current form IMO). But looking over your code I see a number of bugs and other issues:

1. Seeding. You seed with the time, and that leads to seed collisions when creating multiple `UniformRandomGenerator`s within a few milliseconds. You inherit that issue from `System.Random`.
2. `MersenneTwister.NextDouble` is low quality. `double` has about 53 digits, you only fill 32. Almost as bad as `System.Random` which fills 31.
3. `MersenneTwister.Next(int maxValue)` now stretches that bad double over the desired interval. If the interval in long, this can lead to strong biases. `System.Random` has a very similar issue.
4. `Next(int minValue, int maxValue)` contains an int overflow when calculating `maxValue-minValue`
5. The constructor of `NormalRandomGenerator` calculates the mean as `this.Mean = ((max - min) / 2) + min;`. This is an integer division, and thus leads to bias if `max-min` is odd. Strange choice, since `this.Mean` is a double.
6. The code to calculate the normally distributed numbers looks strange too, but I can't help you there, since I don't know what it is supposed to do.

---

If you want to generate uniform random integers, that's a duplicate of my own question: [Generating uniform random integers with a certain maximum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499071/generating-uniform-random-integers-with-a-certain-maximum) , which focuses on creating those integers efficiently without introducing a bias. I recommend combining my answer with LukeH's answer.

Comment: Excellent answer which put all issues together !

Comment: Great code review, thanks for that. But like you said, not an answer to my question.

Comment: @ashes999 If you specify what you actually want, we can answer the question. But currently you ask for something impossible/nonsensical.

Comment: @CodeInChaos Really? Okay, feel free to DV if you feel that's the case.

Comment: @ashes999 I'd prefer an explanation of what you actually want. i.e what distribution you want. Some kind of approximation of the gaussian(since you obviously can't have a real gaussian), but you need to specify how you want to approximate, and how the standard deviation should be calculated(your current calculation makes no sense what so ever).

Comment: @CodeInChaos I'm not sure what it is you don't understand. I have a random number generator that creates a normal distribution. It's discrete (integers), and follows the rules of a "normal" distribution of 60-something percent in one standard dev, 95% in two, and 99% in three. Maybe you can explain what it is you want me to tell you.

Comment: A gaussian is a continuous unbounded distribution. In particular it has values outside of three-sigma. And there are many ways to discretize it. Integrating over partial intervals, picking one point,... all lead to different results. And you obviously don't fulfill the three properties you quote either. And as I said, you didn't give us a specification for how to calculate the standard-deviation from max and min.

Answer (score 0):

Generating random integers by scaling a double in range [0..1) is fine, provided that the generated double is sufficiently evenly distributed. However, most pseudo-random number generators, including Mersenne Twister, natively generate (32-bit unsigned) integers, so it would be nice if we didn't need to make the roundtrip to double.

If the bound N is a power of 2, we can first generate a 32-bit random integer X and take X mod N. This is guaranteed to yield a result with even distribution. But if N is not a power of 2, taking a modulo creates a bias in the resulting distribution (there are more 32-bit unsigned integers for which X mod 7 is 0 than 6, for example.) If N is small, detecting such bias would require a huge number of generated numbers, but theoretically, the distribution will not be right.

To generate integers with truly even distribution in range [0..N) for N that is not a power of two, we can resort to a sampling algorithm: first calculate M such that it is the smallest power of 2 greater than N (for N = 13, M = 16 and so on). Then generate a 32-bit integer X, calculate Y = X mod M. Now, if Y < N, we are done, Y is our number. If Y >= N, discard it and generate another one, until Y < N appears. If the underlying prng is good, the expected number of generated numbers is never more than 2 (it depends on N), and while the loop is not guaranteed to terminate, it will terminate with overwhelming probability. In a practical application, you'd want to put a limiting counter in the loop however and fallback to another method, to guard against degerate generators.

Which method is the fastest? Only profiling will tell. It depends on the hardware, the language and the quality of code.

More thorough discussion can be found in Knuth's TAOCP, part 2.

Answer (score -1):

You can use 'Random.Next Method':

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.next.aspx

You will get a nonnegative random number less than the specified maximum that by your supply or give a range of number (min and max)

Regards.

Comment: Which returns rather low quality numbers. It  probably uses the `NextDouble*max` algorithm. At least that would explain its bias.