# Generate random uint

Tags: c#, random, uint

I need to generate random numbers with range for `byte`, `ushort`, `sbyte`, `short`, `int`, and `uint`. I am able to generate for all those types using the Random method in C# (e.g. `values.Add((int)(random.Next(int.MinValue + 3, int.MaxValue - 2)));`) except for uint since `Random.Next` accepts up to int values only.

Is there an easy way to generate random `uint`?

Comment: Why not just use NextBytes() to get 4 bytes and cast it?

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Certainly possible, but about twice as slow(generates 4 random numbers, one for each byte) compared to combining two values using shifts.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The simplest approach would probably be to use two calls: one for 30 bits and one for the final two. An earlier version of this answer assumed that `Random.Next()` had an *inclusive* upper bound of `int.MaxValue`, but it turns out it's exclusive - so we can only get 30 uniform bits.

```
uint thirtyBits = (uint) random.Next(1 << 30);
uint twoBits = (uint) random.Next(1 << 2);
uint fullRange = (thirtyBits << 2) | twoBits;
```

(You could take it in two 16-bit values of course, as an alternative... or various options in-between.)

Alternatively, you could use `NextBytes` to fill a 4-byte array, then use [`BitConverter.ToUInt32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.touint32.aspx).

Comment: Thanks! Would it also be possible to set the range? And I'm relatively new to programming so I really want to learn how the code works. :)

Comment: @jaqui: Hmm. Possible, but relatively tricky to do in a uniform way. Quite possibly worth a separate question, to be honest.

Comment: @jaqui "Would it also be possible to set the range?" - Related question I asked [Generating uniform random integers with a certain maximum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499071/generating-uniform-random-integers-with-a-certain-maximum)

Comment: @JonSkeet Genuine question: what speaks against [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67003006/7111561)?

Comment: @derHugo: One issue is that it won't cover the full range. That `Random.Next` call will never generate `int.MinValue` or `int.MaxValue`. My solution will generate all possible values, uniformly.

Comment: @JonSkeet oh nice, thanks for clearing this up! :)

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry one last question: Following this theme would this be correctly translated to achieve the same for long `var thirtyBits1 = (long) random.Next(1 << 30); var thirtyBits2 = (long) random.Next(1 << 30); var fourBits = (long) random.Next(1 << 4); var fullRange = (thirtyBits1 << 34) | (thirtyBits2 << 4) | fourBits; return fullRange;` ?

Comment: @derHugo: Just for clarity, I would just declare the variables as `long` rather than declaring them with `var` but casting - but beyond that, it looks okay.

Comment: @JonSkeet Great solution. I really appreciate it. Just one question. Are the (uint) casts necessary? can't thirtyBits and twoBits be int? all in all we need their bits in the end, right?

Comment: @kosmo: They probably could be, but it feels like they're *logically* `uint` in terms of how we're thinking about them, so I'd rather have the slight ugliness of the cast rather than think about the difference in semantics.

Answer (score 22):

## José's Daylight Dices

> Or is there an easy way to generate a true random uint?

I admit, it's not the OQ. It will become clear that there are faster ways to generate random uints which are not true ones. Nevertheless I assume that nobody is too interested in generating those, except when a non-flat distribution is needed for some reason. Let's start with some *research* to get it easy and fast in C#. Easy and fast often behave like synonyms when I write code.

### First: Some important properties

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx).

`Random` constructors:

- `Random()`: Initializes a new instance of the `Random` class, using a time-dependent default seed value.
- `Random(int seed)`: Initializes a new instance of the `Random` class, using the specified seed value.

To improve performance, create one `Random` object to generate many random numbers over time, instead of repeatedly creating new `Random` objects to generate one random number, so:

```
private static Random rand = new Random();
```

`Random` methods:

- `rand.Next()`: Returns a positive random number, greater than or equal to zero, less than `int.MaxValue`.
- `rand.Next(int max)`: Returns a positive random number, greater than or equal to zero, less then max, max must be greater than or equal to zero.
- `rand.Next(int min, int max)`: Returns a positive random number, greater than or equal to min, less then max, max must be greater than or equal to min.

Homework shows that `rand.Next()` is about twice as fast as `rand.Next(int max)`.

### Second: A solution.

Suppose a positive int has only two bits, forget the sign bit, it's zero, `rand.Next()` returns three different values with equal probability:

```
00
01
10
```

For a true random number the lowest bit is zero as often as it is one, same for the highest bit.
To make it work for the lowest bit use: `rand.Next(2)`

Suppose an int has three bits, `rand.Next()` returns seven different values:

```
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
```

To make it work for the lowest two bits use: `rand.Next(4)`

Suppose an int has *n* bits.
To make it work for *n* bits use: `rand.Next(1 << n)`

To make it work for a maximum of 30 bits use: `rand.Next(1 << 30)`
It's the maximum, 1 << 31 is larger than `int.MaxValue`.

Which leads to a way to generate a true random uint:

```
private static uint rnd32()
{
    return (uint)(rand.Next(1 << 30)) << 2 | (uint)(rand.Next(1 << 2));
}
```

> A quick check: What's the chance to generate zero?

1 << 2 = 4 = 2<sup>2</sup>, 1 << 30 = 2<sup>30</sup>

The chance for zero is: 1/2<sup>2</sup> * 1/2<sup>30</sup> = 1/2<sup>32</sup>
The total number of uints, including zero: 2<sup>32</sup>
It's as clear as daylight, no smog alert, isn't it?

### Finally: A misleading idea.

Is it possible to do it faster using `rand.Next()`

```
                            int.Maxvalue is:    (2^31)-1
   The largest value rand.Next() returns is:    (2^31)-2 
                           uint.MaxValue is:    (2^32)-1
```

When `rand.Next()` is used twice and the results are added, the largest possible value is:

```
2*((2^31)-2) = (2^32)-4
```

The difference with uint.MaxValue is:

```
(2^32)-1 - ((2^32)-4) = 3
```

To reach `uint.MaxValue`, another value, `rand.Next(4)` has to be added, thus we get:

rand.Next() + rand.Next() + rand.Next(4)

> What's the chance to generate zero?

Aproximately: 1/2<sup>31</sup> * 1/2<sup>31</sup> * 1/4 = 1/2<sup>64</sup>, it should be 1/2<sup>32</sup>

Wait a second, what about:

```
2 * rand.Next() + rand.Next(4)
```

> Again, what's the chance to generate zero?

Aproximately: 1/2<sup>31</sup> * 1/4 = 1/2<sup>33</sup>, too small to be truly random.

Another easy example:

`rand.Next(2) + rand.Next(2)`, all possible results:

```
       0 + 0 = 0
       0 + 1 = 1
       1 + 0 = 1
       1 + 1 = 2
```

Equal probabilities? No way José.

> Conclusion: The addition of true random numbers gives a random number, but not a true random number. Throw two fair dice ...

Comment: Thank you for the detailed documentation @P_P, It really helps :)

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way to generate random `uint`:

```
uint ui = (uint) new Random().Next(-int.MaxValue, int.MaxValue);
```

Comment: But there is a catch here right, Int & UInt has two different value ranges right!. Int => ( -2147483648 to 2147483647 ) whereas UInt => ( 0 to 4294967295 )

Comment: This expression gives a random number from `0` to `4294967295`

Comment: ((int)-2147483648) cast to (uint) is 4294967295.

Answer (score 1):

**Set the Range, " uint u0 <= returned value <= uint u1 ", using System.Random**

It is easier to start with a range from "zero" (inclusive) to "u" (inclusive).
You might take a look at my other 
[answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18332307/1673752)
If you are interested in a faster/more efficient way:
[Uniform pseudo random numbers in a range.](http://bigintegers.blogspot.com/2013/10/uniform-pseudo-random-numbers-in-range.html) (It is quite a lot of code/text).

Below "rnd32(uint u)" returns: 0 <= value <= u .
The most difficult case is: "u = int.MaxValue". Then the chance that the first iteration of the "do-loops"
(a single iteration of both the outer and the inner "do-loop"), returns a valid value is 50%.
 After two iterations, the chance is 75%, etc.

The chance is small that the outer "do-loop" iterates more than one time.
In the case of "u = int.MaxValue": 0%.

It is obvious that: "rnd32(uint u0, uint u1)" returns a value between u0 (incl) and u1 (incl).

```
private static Random rand = new Random();

private static uint rnd32(uint u)                                 //  0 <= x <= u
{
    uint x;
    if (u < int.MaxValue) return (uint)rand.Next((int)u + 1);
    do                                         
    {
        do x = (uint)rand.Next(1 << 30) << 2;
        while (x > u);
        x |= (uint)rand.Next(1 << 2);
    }
    while (x > u);
    return x;
}

private static uint rnd32(uint u0, uint u1)                      // set the range
{
    return u0 < u1 ? u0 + rnd32(u1 - u0) : u1 + rnd32(u0 - u1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shorely its as simple as this little example with min and max uint range?:

```
public static class Utility
{
    public static uint RandomUInt(uint min, uint max, Random? rand = null)
    {
        if (min > max) (min, max) = (max, min);
        int intMin = (int)(int.MinValue + min);
        int intMax = (int)(int.MinValue + max);
        int rInt = rand?.Next(intMin, intMax) ?? new Random().Next(intMin, intMax);
        return (uint)(int.MaxValue + rInt + 1);
    }
}

Utility.RandomUInt(3000000000, 3000000010);
```

Output:

```
| 3000000005
| 3000000001
| 3000000009
```